# How can I access the output history of my shell or terminal-emulator?

Tags: bash, terminal, buffer, gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator

Terminal emulators obviously save a portion of the output history of any command in a buffer. We know this, because, e.g. in `gnome-terminal` there are scrollbars on the right and we can scroll back and look at a "history" of what commands we have typed with a limit of scrollback lines.

[image: scroolback]

**Is there a way to access this buffered information and use it from within a shell command?** 
I'm not dead set on `gnome-terminal` as the emulator. Any of the commonly used, decently featured ones that can do this would be fine.

I now I could just rerun the command, i.e. do something like `echo "$(!!)"`. But that has two limitations:

- The command executes again, with all side-effects, taking time and resources. (which is annoying for long-running commands)
- The command output might change on re-runs (e.g. `date`)

Here is an example terminal session, that illustrates what I want:

```
confus@confusion6 ~/devel/dmenu master $ ls
LICENSE   config.def.h  dmenu.c     dmenu_run  stest    util.c
Makefile  config.h      dmenu.o     drw.c      stest.c  util.h
README    config.mk     dmenu.1     drw.h      stest.o  util.o
arg.h     dmenu         dmenu_path  drw.o      stest.1  safe.c

confus@confusion6 ~/devel/dmenu master $ make
dmenu build options:
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Os -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -DVERSION="4.9" -DXINERAMA
LDFLAGS  = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXinerama -lfontconfig -lXft
CC       = cc

confus@confusion6 ~/devel/dmenu master $ date
Sa May 11 16:28:08 CEST 2019

confus@confusion6 ~/devel/dmenu master $ get_output_buffer | grep -i sa  # Does not re-run the commands!
arg.h     dmenu         dmenu_path  drw.o      stest.1  safe.c
Sa May 11 16:28:08 CEST 2019
```

Here the imaginary function `get_outpuf_buffer` would access the terminal's output buffer and print that to `stdout` for further processing. Maybe there is a bash built-in feature that can be used similarly or a terminal-emulator that has my wanted feature?

Comment: Can you run `script` from your `.bashrc`? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/200637/133219. Also google tmux, screen, and xclip.

Comment: `script` has the  small drawback, that you can't do things like `cat script`, essentially writing a file of infinite size and blocking the shell. Also does it duplicate the data rather than drawing on an already existent scrollback buffer. As far as I know, tmux and screen don't grant buffer access from within the running shell. But the suggestion **is nice**. I did not know of `script`.

Comment: Well, then [xclip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) and [xsel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel) are my last ideas. Good luck :-) !

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `tee` tool before all your commands.  This way, you can store all your output in a selected file. See the example below where I save all the output to a text file called `log.txt`:

```
bash | tee log.txt
echo 'hello world'
cat log.txt
```

You can exit the new `BASH` session with a CTRL+D or `exit` when you're done.

Comment: I'm **not** talking about command history, I'm talking about **output-history**. Please read more closely.

Comment: Sorry about that, you are right... I misread the question. I modified my answer with a hopefully more useful answer.

Comment: Thank you, that is a solution, yay! :-) However it's a bit sad, that one has to duplicate the output with tee and it's an extra manual step. I'd prefer something that is built into bash or the terminal-emulator and works without having to remember to start the terminal differently.